# HTML Search Bar

Tags: html, search

I don't know how to put it exactly, so here goes.

I've created a search bar on my webpage that uses your input text to search another website. 
This is what I've got (things have been censored):

```
<form name="search" class="form-search" method="get" action="http://www.nameofwebsite.com/search.php?">  
<input name="searchbynum" type="text" class="search-query input-large" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)">  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>  
</form>
```

When searching on the actual website, the search URL looks like this:

```
http://www.nameofwebsite.com/search.php?searchbynum=search+phrase&searchbydesc=&Submit=Go
```

Where "search+phrase" is what is searched. To get to the point,
**What would I have to do to add the "&searchbydesc=&Submit=Go" at the end of the search?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add hidden fields to your page.

```
<form ...>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="searchbydesc" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Submit" value="Go" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Note that your HTML as it is, is invalid. A `<form>` element cannot have `<input />` elements as immediate children, they must be wrapped in a `<div>` or `<fieldset>` or other similar elements.